# Fixing date & time format in HTML

Tags: python, django, date-formatting

## Context of Question

Hi all, I'm building a Twitter clone. I'm using JavaScript to create & insert a new Tweet into the news feed.

After inserting the new Tweet into the news feed, I noticed the date & time format is different after refreshing the page. Examples below for reference:

### Tweet after inserting into news feed & before refreshing the page

[image]

### Tweet after refreshing the page

[image]

The Tweet in JSON format looks like this

```
  {
    "id": 56,
    "user": "admin",
    "content": "yes",
    "date": "Feb 07 2023, 12:26 AM",
    "likes": 0
  }
```

I'm using Django as the backend & the how a Tweet gets serialized is as follows:

```
def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "user": self.user.username,
            "content": self.content,
            "date": self.date.strftime("%b %d %Y, %I:%M %p"),
            "likes": self.likes
        }
```

Now, I'm not sure what's causing this mismatch of date & time format:

- the serializer for the Tweet, or
- how HTML handles the date & time format

Django template for Tweet

```
  <small class="text-muted tweet-date">{{tweet.date}}</small>
```

`JavaScript` code for inserting Tweet

```
function createTweet(tweetJsonObject) {
    // clone Tweet from Tweet template
    let newTweet = document.querySelector(".tweet-template").cloneNode(true);
    newTweet.style.display = "block";
    newTweet.querySelector(".tweet-date").textContent = tweetJsonObject.date;
    newTweet.querySelector(".tweet-content").textContent = tweetJsonObject.content;
    newTweet.querySelector(".tweet-likes").textContent = tweetJsonObject.likes;
    newTweet.dataset.id = tweetJsonObject.id;
    // remove tweet-template & add tweet class
    newTweet.classList.remove('tweet-template');
    newTweet.classList.add('tweet');

    return newTweet;
}
```

Comment: When you refresh, is the date being rendered in a Django template? Can you show the part of the template where the date is rendered and the JS too?

Comment: hi @IainShelvington, i've included the Django template & JS code, thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date) filter to format a date in a Django template

The following format string should match the output of the one used in your JSON

```
  <small class="text-muted tweet-date">{{ tweet.date|date:"M d Y, h:i A" }}</small>
```